# Is there anything special about a list box on a page control?

Tags: vba, forms, selection

I don’t understand why my click event isn’t running when I select a row in a listbox.

I have a userform in Excel, and it contains a page control. I’ve added two pages to the control. I have a listbox, lstRisks, on the first page. When I select a row in this control, it correctly triggers the Click event. On the second page, I have a listbox name lstUnassignedRisks. And when I select a row, it ignores me and just laughs at me.

Comment: It is very hard to debug without more information.  Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve], otherwise there is no way for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

My testing found out why selecting an item in the listbox isn’t triggering the code, and it doesn’t have anything to do with being on a page.

The second listbox is set up as multiselect, and it the Click event isn’t active for multiselect listboxes. The answer is to use the Change event instead of the Click event